# Ionic include only used ionicicons

Tags: ionic-framework

By default my `angular.json` will include the whole ionicon set as follows:

```
"assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*.svg",
            "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
            "output": "./svg"
          }
        ],
```

Since Im using custom icons set, I have removed the above from my assets array but this also removed back icon from `<ion-back-button>`, any idea how can I import only the ionicicons I am using and avoid including the whole icon pack in my app?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add custom icons for  you can do the following :

- create file in themes and name it icons.scss for example
- in that file put your icons like this : suppose your icon name will be "products" and the icon file name called " menu.svg "

  ```
    ion-icon {
   &[class*="products"] {

    mask-size: contain;

   mask-position: 50% 50%;

   mask-repeat: no-repeat;

   width: 1em; // for example 

   height: 1em;// for example 

   background: #yourColor ;

   mask-image: url('../assets/menu.svg');



  }
  ```

}

- in app.scss add `@import '../theme/icons';` 
  and if you don't want to use default icons , remove `@import "ionic.ionicons";`
  from variables.scss in themes